# Shinyapp.io cannot load rgdal package

Tags: shiny, leaflet, rgdal, r-sf, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that is working locally, that loads several packages, including rgdal, which is installed locally on my MacOS. When I deploy it on shinyapp.io server it seems like the server cannot find the rgdal installation. I have seen that other people have similar problems with rgdal but I cannot seem to find a way to fix it.

I have tried to reinstall the rgdal package from the terminal but also this does not work.

The error I get when I deploy on the server is:

```
Error in value[3L] : package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object '/opt/R/3.5.0/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so': /opt/R/3.5.0/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10OGRFeature11SetGeometryEP11OGRGeometry Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> Execution halted
```

How can I install the rgdal package in `/opt/R/3.5.0/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/`? My understanding is that this should solve the issue as the server is looking in that folder for the installation.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-

Comment: I have already gone through all the common issues. Mine does not fall in the listed ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within Shinyapps.io , under the app's advanced settings, I unchecked the "Package Cache" and then redeployed.  Then it worked. This solution was suggested by the rstudio support team.